# Curry generic function with Ramda and Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, ramda.js, currying

I have a generic function:

```
function hello<T>(n: number, s: string, thing: T): Array<T> {
  return [thing]
}

const result = hello(1, 'string arg', 'generic arg')
```

`result` has type `string[]` which is expected.

However if I curry it:

```
function hello<T>(n: number, s: string, thing: T): Array<T> {
  return [thing]
}

const fun1 = curry(hello)(1, 'string arg')

const result = fun1('generic arg')
```

`result` now has type `unknown[]`.

How can I curry a generic function in Ramda whilst maintaining the type?  I'm using Ramda 0.27.1

Comment: Ramda was written as a JS library, not a TS one.  The Ramda team has never worried overmuch about Typescript typings.  For a long time, TS had no mechanisms to handle more complex Ramda types.  That may have changed, but I wouldn't be surprised if you still need to manually type such results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `R.curry` with 3 parameters is:

```
curry<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(fn: (a: T1, b: T2, c: T3) => TResult): CurriedFunction3<T1, T2, T3, TResult>;
```

As you can see, you'll need to manually type the curried function ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/curry-ts-ramda-151iwc?file=/src/index.ts)):

```
function hello<T>(n: number, s: string, thing: T): Array<T> {
  return [thing];
}

const fun1 = curry<number, string, string, string[]>(hello)(1, 'string arg');

const result = fun1('generic arg');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `ramda: "^0.29.1"`, I came up with the following solution:

```
function hello<T>(n: number, s: string, thing: T): Array<T> {
    return [thing];
}

const fun1 = R.curry(hello<string>)(1, "string arg");

const result = fun1("generic arg");
```

The trick is to pass the type parameter at the time of creating the curried function. After that, you should receive the correct output type (i.e. `string[]`).